# unable to set the state of an array of objects of a functional component using the setState hook in react

Tags: react-hooks, setstate, react-functional-component

I have a piece of code wherein I am trying to change the state of an array of objects (I want to clear it out) when certain conditions are met. The conditions I have written are correct but I am unable to change the state of the array using the setState hook. I'll add the code snippets below and try to explain further

This is how we are initialising the state variable 'arrayOfObjects'.

```
const [arrayOfObjects, setArrayOfObjects] = useState(
        objects.map(object => ({
            id: `${object.type}`,
            value: false,
            text: object.name,
            privilege: object.privilege,
            disabled: false
        }))
    );
```

Later on in the code I am checking certain conditions and trying to empty out the arrayOfObjects state variable as below

`setArrayOfObjects([])`

This doesn't give me an error but it also doesn't work. The objects array always has data in it. Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

I also tried

`setArrayOfObjects(arrayOfObjects.filter(arrayOfObjects => arrayOfObjects.privilege !== 12345678));`

but that didn't work as well.

I also tried the following but I am fairly new to React and don't know if I am doing this correctly. This also didn't work

```
useEffect(() => {
setArrayOfObjects([])
}, [arrayOfObjects])
```

I also tried to create a type for the arrayOfObjects array and used that where the state variables are initialised but got an error

```
interface ITestInterface extends IListOption {
    privilege: number | null;
}
```

The IListOption is as follows

```
export interface IListOption {
    id: string;
    text: string;
    value: boolean;
    disabled?: boolean;
}
```

Used as below

```
const [arrayOfObjects, setArrayOfObjects] = useState<IPrivilegeListOption | undefined>(
        objects.map(object => ({
            id: `${object.type}`,
            value: false,
            text: object.name,
            privilege: object.privilege,
            disabled: false
        }))
    );
```

The error I get is

> Argument of type '{ id: string; value: boolean; text: string; privilege: number | null; disabled: boolean; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ITestInterface | (() => ITestInterface | undefined) | undefined'.

I am not sure what else I could try